# Neo4J 3.1.3 graph database access remotely

Tags: javascript, c#, neo4j

I was new to Neo4J 3.0 graph database.I have some issue with neo4j.

By default it works for localhost and works fine http://localhost:7474/browser/. Now I want to allow access to everybody.I install neo4j in remote server and i try to change Server configuration in options 
"dbms.connector.http.listen_address={MyIpAddress}:7474" but not working.

```
#***************************************************************
# Server configuration
#

# #{settings-reference.url}
dbms.directories.import=import

# Require (or disable the requirement of) auth to access Neo4j
dbms.security.auth_enabled=true

# With default configuration Neo4j only accepts local connections.
# To accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
#dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0

# You can also choose a specific network interface, and configure a non-default
# port for each connector, by setting their individual listen_address.

# The address at which this server can be reached by its clients. This may be the server's IP address or DNS name, or
# it may be the address of a reverse proxy which sits in front of the server. This setting may be overridden for
# individual connectors below.`enter code here`
dbms.connectors.default_advertised_address=localhost

# You can also choose a specific advertised hostname or IP address, and
# configure an advertised port for each connector, by setting their
# individual advertised_address.

# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:7687

# HTTP Connector

dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7474


# HTTPS Connector
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.https.listen_address=:#{default.https:port}

# Certificates directory
# dbms.directories.certificates=certificates


# Administration client configuration


# Comma separated list of JAX-RS packages containing JAX-RS resources, one
# package name for each mountpoint. The listed package names will be loaded
# under the mountpoints specified. Uncomment this line to mount the
# org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged.HelloWorldResource.java from
# neo4j-examples under /examples/unmanaged, resulting in a final URL of
# http://localhost:${default.http.port}/examples/unmanaged/helloworld/{nodeId}
#dbms.unmanaged_extension_classes=org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged=/examples/unmanaged


# HTTP logging configuration

# HTTP logging is disabled. HTTP logging can be enabled by setting this
# property to 'true'.
dbms.logs.http.enabled=false

# Enable this to be able to upgrade a store from an older version.
#dbms.allow_format_migration=true


#dbms.memory.pagecache.size=10g

# Enable this to specify a parser other than the default one.
#cypher.default_language_version=2.0


#dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=7 days

# Enable shell server so that remote clients can connect via Neo4j shell.
#dbms.shell.enabled=true
# The network interface IP the shell will listen on (use 0.0.0.0 for all interfaces).
#dbms.shell.host=127.0.0.1
# The port the shell will listen on, default is 1337.
#dbms.shell.port=1337
```

**Errors**

If I enter the url with my ip address, I get "This site can’t be reached"

If I enter router ip address asking for login, I get the error:

`N/A: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common reasons include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL or temporary network problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure your browser is configured to trust the certificate Neo4j is configured to use. WebSocket 'readyState' is: 3`

I want to access my neo4j in everybody using url.

Comment: you should change it to 0.0.0.0:7474

Comment: I tried but getting error  org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer$ServerComponentsLifecycleAdapter@6dc3fd85

Comment: please paste your current configuration (complete) as well as the full stacktrace you get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The neo4j browser uses by default Bolt for connecting to the database.

Two solutions :

a) you set the bolt port as well for 0.0.0.0

dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687

b) you disable bolt in the browser :

[image]

Comment: Hi thanx its working router level means with in cable it's working but i want give the url for out side to access how to do this ?

Comment: I want to give public IP address of my server  to access the neo4j db to every one