# Not able to connect with Neo4j Desktop Online

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-desktop

I have newly started Neo4j, for this I have downloaded **Neo4j Desktop version- 1.1.22**, but it always says **No Internet connection.**

[image]

On developer tools, I have found the below issue.

[image]

Does anyone has resolved this issue?

Comment: I asked this on the Neo4j community but couldn't get the solution. So I downloaded the older version which worked for me. If you are stuck you can try previous versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some issue with new versions of Neo4j Desktop.
I was facing the same issue for these versions **1.1.17, 1.1.18, 1.1.20 and 1.1.21** on Windows.

I have reverted back to version `1.1.15` It's working as expected.

**You can download 1.1.15 [here](https://neo4j.com/download-thanks-desktop/?edition=desktop&flavour=winstall64&release=1.1.15&offline=true&_ga=2.195015597.1474490258.1559108950-1401967082.1535706424).**

Comment: thanks for providing solution. But I am not able to connect in Neo4j Browser, It always throws an error:- "ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development...

Comment: This error is different from the above. Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406145/websocket-connection-failure-due-to-security-constraints-in-your-web-browser