# Neo4J: N/A: WebSocket connection failure.

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j

G'day.
Installed neo4j (v3.0.5 according to the browser) on AWS (ubuntu). No matter what i try, when i connect to the db i get this error:

"WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common reasons include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL or temporary network problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure your browser is configured to trust the certificate Neo4j is configured to use. WebSocket readyState is: 3"

Tried making sure the relevant connections to bolt etc are open... but problem persists.
Anyone got any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neo4J 3.1.3 graph database access remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44156066/neo4j-3-1-3-graph-database-access-remotely)

Answer (score 0):

After a day of searching, it turns out that the default security policy from EC2 in AWS doesn't include the port for bolt (7687). Had to add this manually to the security policy rules (inbound) for this EC2 instance.

Also, since this may come up in future searches for someone, the default password for Neo4J in AWS is the name of the instance ID.